# Swift updating text when pressing button

Tags: swift, button, view, toggle

i made an app with credits, where when a certain button is pressed, it will dedact 1 credit. Now comes the strange thing: when I use a toggle, the text label immediately updates to the correct number that is left (each toggle is -1). When I press a normal button, it does 1 time. When I do this multiple times with the normal button, it does not visually change. However when I toggle again, it takes of all the times I pressed the regular button as well. In both the toggle and button I have exactly the same `Func`, so that should be good. Is there something that is different in those two, when updating a view? The only thing I can think of is when the toggle turns green, it forces a refresh.

Comment: Sure will do that. I figured out that a ```$Binding``` works when getting data from user settings, but a self. or just the Var is only changing on app restart.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution: I was not actually publishing the publishers actively. Solved and closed.